# how can we store multiple fields values across different pages before submitting at the last page.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui

how can we store multiple fields values across different pages before submitting at the last page. What is the best method?. I have create User controls and placed them  in a single page and this helped me to save the field values as they are on one single page. But when i click on back button of browser it loses data. How can I prevent it from losing data.

What is the best method other than using user controls?. Im using VB.NET.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the data in session object and then when you press the back button, restore the saved data from session.

Comment: thanks, yeah session works. Is there any other way of doing this. I'm actually exploring the possibilities and want to follow the best practice.

Comment: You have to understand the concept that web is stateless. so there is no other way rather than saving the data somewhere, it can be database, session, cookies etc.

Comment: thanks im accepting this as the answer .And one final question , is there a possibility to store all the objects in a single session variable. If so small example will help.

Comment: Yes you can. it will be a piece of cake.